# Set scope variable on typeahead directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive setup to use `typeahead.js` along with angular as follows:

```
app.directive('typeahead', function(ergastAPI){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        ergastAPI.getCityDetails().success(function(data){
            var vals = data.response[0].vals;
            var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                local: $.map(vals, function(d) {
                    return {
                        value:d.name,
                        suggest: d
                    }
                })
            });
            suggestions.initialize();
            $(element[0]).typeahead({
                minLength: 1,
                hint: true,
                highlight: true
            },{
                name: "suggestions",
                displayKey: "value",
                templates:{
                    suggestion: function(data){
                        var details = '<div class="suggest-drop"><span class="" style="margin-right:15px;"></span>'+data.value+'</div>';
                        return details;
                    },
                    header: '<div class="suggest-header">Car</div>'
                },
                source: suggestions.ttAdapter()
            }).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(e, s, n){                  
                scope.query = s.value;
            });;
        });
    }
});
```

This is being used in my html as follows:

```
<input class="input-picker" ng-model="query" typeahead id="type-element" />
```

What I want to do is, on selection of a typeahead option, set the `scope.query` value to be equal to the value that has been selected. However, the above method doesn't seem to work. How do I set the scope of the parent controller based on the value selected within this directive?

Comment: set the scope to false, you may need to change the code a little, so that it returns an object with scope as false and link function as the function you are returning. What seems to me is that, the directive is creating a child hescope and it you change a variable it inherited from the parent, it will change in child scope(directive's) but not in parent scope(controller's). By default it is true, so the directive is having its own scope

Comment: Also console the value of scope.query in directive to check if it is changing in the directive. If it is changing in directive but not in controller, then its a scope issue, else it seems a function issue.

Comment: @TheJugadGuru, is it possible for you to show me some code? I couldn't quite understand your solution

Comment: Ignore the first comment, that happens when you have multiple directives on a html element. I am asking you to console the value of the scope.query before and after you assign it the selected value. Now select different options from the dropdown and see if the previous changes are reflected or not. Means, the scope variable inside the directive might be  updating with each selection of option. This tells you , it is a child/parent scope issue. Try this.

Comment: modify your code like : .on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(e, s, n){       
                console.log("Before:", scope.query);
                scope.query = s.value;
                console.log("After:", scope.query);
            });;

now select options multiple times and check the console if the previous selection is getting printed or not.

Comment: @TheJugadGuru It shows `Before: a`, `After: Apple` and on next try, `Before: ca`, `After: Car`

Comment: Then it is a  parent child scope issue. Either try to make the scope same, or use a property. Example, create $scope.query = {value: ""}; Now, use query.value in both ng-model and directive. It should work.